# Android Studio, need to HIDE TabLayout instead of making it invisible

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, show-hide, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I currently have the following code to make TabLayout invisible:

```
   final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

What the above code does is make the TabLayout and tab fragments invisible but it stays in the same spot. I need to make it hide and move ABOVE the screen.

```
    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout....?
```

As the above states, what code would I need for the TabLayout to actually move above the screen and hide instead of be invisible and stay in same spot?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: No, GONE has the same result as INVISIBLE. Is there anyway to actually make TabLayout move?

Comment: GONE should cause them to no longer take up space.

It's a bit cheap, but you could force the TabLayout to have a width and height of 0px and see if that would work. You'd want to record those dimensions first before you shrink it.